# How to read MP3 file tags

Tags: java, mp3, metadata, id3

I want to have a program that reads metadata from an MP3 file. My program should also able to edit these metadata. What can I do?

I got to search out for some open source code. But they have code; but not simplified idea for my job they are going to do.

When I read further I found the metadata is stored in the MP3 file itself. But I am yet not able to make a full idea of my baby program.

Any help will be appreciated; with a program or very idea (like an algorithm). :)

Comment: [http://www.id3.org/Implementations](http://www.id3.org/Implementations) would be a good place to start

Comment: [jd3lib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jd3lib/) is a Java library that handles MP3s, and their tags. Probably a useful starting point.

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527169/whats-the-easiest-way-to-extract-the-jpg-data-from-an-mp3-header-in-java Plus a lot more of MP3 stuff in search: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+mp3

Comment: I am using jd3lib, but it appears that it is slow, and uses too much memory.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The last 128 bytes of a mp3 file contains meta data about the mp3 file., You can write a program to read the last 128 bytes...

UPDATE:

ID3v1 Implementation

The Information is stored in the last 128 bytes of an MP3. The Tag
   has got the following fields, and the offsets given here, are from
   0-127.

```
 Field      Length    Offsets
 Tag        3           0-2
 Songname   30          3-32
 Artist     30         33-62
 Album      30         63-92
 Year       4          93-96
 Comment    30         97-126
 Genre      1           127
```

WARINING- This is just an ugly way of getting metadata and it might not actually be there because the world has moved to id3v2. id3v1 is actually obsolete. Id3v2 is more complex than this, so ideally you should use existing libraries to read id3v2 data from mp3s . Just putting this out there.

Comment: @ChssPly76 ofcourse it depends on the version. Not ALL info will be in the last 128 bytes. But this is a simple approach if you just want to get data from mp3s that have id3 and id1 metadata.

Comment: I meant id3v1 and id3v2 not id3 & id1

Comment: Nice Jass; This much info i wanted to know from all the oceans of code and text i was stuck in to. Thanks will write my program and let you all know. 

@ Martijn Courteaux does this really works all the time.

Comment: Fair enough. The latest version, however, is id3v2.4 and you'll be missing a lot of stuff by restricting yourself to v1. More importantly, it's rather pointless to try to do this by hand when there are perfectly good libraries available that do it for you. Look at `Brian Agnew`'s answer as well as links in my comment - this has been asked (and answered) before.

Comment: You are right. Libraries is the best way to go. But sometimes you just want to get the dirty work done.. I just gave an answer i knew. I dont know about v2. I should probably put a warning or something... hmm

Answer (score 18):

You can use **apache tika** Java API for meta-data parsing from MP3 such as *title, album, genre, duraion, composer, artist and etc*.. required jars are **tika-parsers-1.4, tika-core-1.4.**

***Sample Program:***

```
package com.parse.mp3;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException;
import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;
import org.apache.tika.parser.ParseContext;
import org.apache.tika.parser.Parser;
import org.apache.tika.parser.mp3.Mp3Parser;
import org.xml.sax.ContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class AudioParser {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileLocation = "G:/asas/album/song.mp3";

        try {

        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(fileLocation));
        ContentHandler handler = new DefaultHandler();
        Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
        Parser parser = new Mp3Parser();
        ParseContext parseCtx = new ParseContext();
        parser.parse(input, handler, metadata, parseCtx);
        input.close();

        // List all metadata
        String[] metadataNames = metadata.names();

        for(String name : metadataNames){
        System.out.println(name + ": " + metadata.get(name));
        }

        // Retrieve the necessary info from metadata
        // Names - title, xmpDM:artist etc. - mentioned below may differ based
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Title: " + metadata.get("title"));
        System.out.println("Artists: " + metadata.get("xmpDM:artist"));
        System.out.println("Composer : "+metadata.get("xmpDM:composer"));
        System.out.println("Genre : "+metadata.get("xmpDM:genre"));
        System.out.println("Album : "+metadata.get("xmpDM:album"));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TikaException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a good solution to read mp3 meta data, but using tika I believe we can not update mp3 meta data.

Comment: Awesome solution! Thanks you.

Comment: What's the 2020 version of that `Mp3Parser()` does not seem to exist anymore.

Comment: @StefanFalk You need to import the required dependencies. Add [Apache Tika AudioVideo Parser Module](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tika/tika-parser-audiovideo-module/2.0.0) maven dependency to your `pom.xml` file

Answer (score 2):

For J2ME(which is what I was struggling with), here's the code that worked for me..

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.microedition.io.file.FileConnection;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;
import javax.microedition.media.Manager;
import javax.microedition.media.Player;
import javax.microedition.media.control.MetaDataControl;
import javax.microedition.midlet.MIDlet;

public class MetaDataControlMIDlet extends MIDlet implements CommandListener {
  private Display display = null;
  private List list = new List("Message", List.IMPLICIT);
  private Command exitCommand = new Command("Exit", Command.EXIT, 1);
  private Alert alert = new Alert("Message");
  private Player player = null;  

  public MetaDataControlMIDlet() {    
    display = Display.getDisplay(this);
    alert.addCommand(exitCommand);
    alert.setCommandListener(this);
    list.addCommand(exitCommand);
    list.setCommandListener(this);
    //display.setCurrent(list);

  }

  public void startApp() {
      try {
      FileConnection connection = (FileConnection) Connector.open("file:///e:/breathe.mp3");
      InputStream is = null;
      is = connection.openInputStream();
      player = Manager.createPlayer(is, "audio/mp3");
      player.prefetch();
      player.realize();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      alert.setString(e.getMessage());
      display.setCurrent(alert);
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (player != null) {
      MetaDataControl mControl = (MetaDataControl) player.getControl("javax.microedition.media.control.MetaDataControl");
      if (mControl == null) {
        alert.setString("No Meta Information");
        display.setCurrent(alert);
      } else {
        String[] keys = mControl.getKeys();
        for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
          list.append(keys[i] + " -- " + mControl.getKeyValue(keys[i]), null);
        }
        display.setCurrent(list);
      }
    }
  }

  public void commandAction(Command cmd, Displayable disp) {
    if (cmd == exitCommand) {
      notifyDestroyed();
    }
  }

  public void pauseApp() {
  }

  public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
  }

}
```