# extracting tags of a song

Tags: java, file, audio-fingerprinting

How can I extract tags(album, artist, album art, etc) from an mp3 file using java? I need all the tags of my songs to be stored at one particular file so that I can use it as a database.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to read mp3 file tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645803/how-to-read-mp3-file-tags)

Comment: http://javamusictag.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @paul: thanks. i tried but it shows an error "failed to main-class manifest attribute from .." any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Tika:
http://tika.apache.org/

this metadata extracted by Tika for MP3 file:

```
Author: /ÅÍÓÜÜÇÓ ..
Content-Length: 4232049
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
channels: 2
resourceName: droob_al-hayat.MP3
samplerate: 44100
title: 
version: MPEG 3 Layer III Version 1
xmpDM:album: 
xmpDM:artist: /ÅÍÓÜÜÇÓ ..
xmpDM:audioChannelType: Stereo
xmpDM:audioCompressor: MP3
xmpDM:audioSampleRate: 44100
xmpDM:composer: null
xmpDM:genre: 
xmpDM:logComment: 
xmpDM:releaseDate:
```