# Getting media tag (.mp3, m4a)

Tags: c#, metadata, media, id3

I am writing a program that collects information from a media file that is selected. I would like to get things like: Artist, Album, Genre, Time, year. All the basic stuff. Now I have searched Stack to find another form post like the one I am creating and no one has one so here going nothing.

I would like to retrieve all this information without using any third party libraries.

I have found, though, this snippet of code.

```
byte[] b = new byte[128];
string sTitle;
string sSinger;
string sAlbum;
string sYear;
string sComm;

FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\Music\Led Zeppelin - Discography\01. Studio albums\04. Led Zeppelin IV (1971)\01. Black Dog.mp3", FileMode.Open);
fs.Seek(-128, SeekOrigin.End);
fs.Read(b, 0, 128);
bool isSet = false;
String sFlag = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(b, 0, 3);
if (sFlag.CompareTo("TAG") == 0)
 {
  System.Console.WriteLine("Tag   is   setted! ");
  isSet = true;
 }

if (isSet)
 {
//get   title   of   song; 
 sTitle = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(b, 3, 30);
 System.Console.WriteLine("Title: " + sTitle);
//get   singer; 
 sSinger = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(b, 33, 30);
System.Console.WriteLine("Singer: " + sSinger);
//get   album; 
 sAlbum = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(b, 63, 30);
 System.Console.WriteLine("Album: " + sAlbum);
//get   Year   of   publish; 
 sYear = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(b, 93, 4);
 System.Console.WriteLine("Year: " + sYear);
//get   Comment; 
 sComm = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(b, 97, 30);
 System.Console.WriteLine("Comment: " + sComm);
}
 System.Console.Read();
```

I do not understand how it is getting the information that it gets.
How does the

```
sTitle = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(b, 3, 30);
```

Get the song title.

Also, when I get the information, I want to customize it and then SET it again.

Any help, Thanks :)

Comment: MP3 file structure: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3#File_structure then you want the ID structure: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `b` is the byte that I created which is the place where the MetaData is stored in the mp3. It is stored in the last 128 bytes of the file. And the number after the `b` is the offset. Basically where the certain info is stored in the .MP3 file.

```
Field      Length    Offsets
Tag        3           0-2
Songname   30          3-32
Artist     30         33-62
Album      30         63-92
Year       4          93-96
Comment    30         97-126
Genre      1           127
```

Answer (score 1):

The MP3 ID tag structure is described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3

```
Field   Length      Description
header  3       "TAG"
title   30      30 characters of the title
artist  30      30 characters of the artist name
album   30      30 characters of the album name
year    4       A four-digit year
comment     28 or 30    The comment.
zero-byte   1       If a track number is stored, this byte contains a binary 0.
track   1       The number of the track on the album, or 0. Invalid, if previous byte is not a binary 0.
genre   1       Index in a list of genres, or 255
```

EDIT - to overwrite the string again, you'll want to do something like this:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\Music\Led Zeppelin - Discography\01. Studio albums\04. Led Zeppelin IV (1971)\01. Black Dog.mp3", FileMode.Open);
fs.Seek(-128 + 3, SeekOrigin.End);  //-128 to ID tag, +3 to title
byte[] title = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Black Dog");
fs.Write(title, 0, title.Length);
```

Comment: Thank you for the resources. But what does the `b` and `3` mean in... `sTitle = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(b, 3, 30);` I found the answer, they are offsets. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645803/how-to-read-mp3-file-tags?rq=1

Comment: yes `GetString(b, 3, 30)` means read the buffer (b), get the (30) bytes starting from the (3)rd one and format it as a string