# How to getAttribute of a mp3 files 'Title' and 'Author'

Tags: java

```
public Track createNewTrack(File file) throws IOException {
    Path path = file.toPath(); 
    String trackName = (String) Files.getAttribute(path, "Title"); //get name of track from file
    String artist = (String) Files.getAttribute(path, "Authors"); //get artist from file
    String filePath = file.getPath(); //get file path from file
    Track track = new Track(trackName, artist, filePath);
    return track;
}
```

For some reason it's not finding the attribute...Can anyone help me to why that might be?

Answer (score -1):

A **File** can be something different than a mp3 file. So it doesn't always have those attributes and the **File** Class does not provide them.

You have to read those attributes yourself. See: [How to read MP3 file tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645803/how-to-read-mp3-file-tags)

Answer (score -1):

Files.getAttribute reads filesystem attributes; mp3 metadata is not generally available in filesystems, but is stored in the file contents using the ID3 format. You need a library that understands ID3.