# how to get data from an mp3 file and put it on html automatically?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, mp3

Does anyone know how to get specific data from an mp3 file and also automatically putting it in `HTML`?

For example this data:

[image]

And let's say that I want all that data to be placed in a HTML table like this:

```
<table class="pl5 lh1-4"><tr>
    <td>Artist/Band:</td>
    <td>PLACEHOLDER</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>Album:</td>
    <td>PLACEHOLDER</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>Gerne:</td>
    <td>PLACEHOLDER</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>Duration:</td>
    <td>PLACEHOLDER</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>Release date:</td>
    <td>PLACEHOLDER</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>Size:</td>
    <td>PLACEHOLDER</td>
  </tr></table>
<table class="pl5 lh1-4"><tr><td>
 1. PLACEHOLDER<br>
 2. PLACEHOLDER<br>
 3. PLACEHOLDER<br>
 4. PLACEHOLDER<br>
</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: Have you done any reasearch? A quick google throws this up https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645803/how-to-read-mp3-file-tags

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/aadsm/jsmediatags

I found this library, never tried it myself so you have to thinker with it