# Read .mp3 files from a folder and sort them in a list

Tags: web-development-server

I'm planning to build a self hosted music streaming service for myself only.

I'm new to web development so it'd be quite delightful to have someone course me in the right direction.

So, it's gonna be a simple static HTML&CSS website that I'm going to host on apache server.

Then, as it comes to functionality, it suppose to read .mp3 files from a folder and sort them in
a list of:

```
Artist1 - Song1   2:35
Artist2 - Song2   3:56
Artist3 - Song3   1:24
```

tangible elements that I can click on and it will retrieve the audio content from a folder.
Of course I'm expecting the code to do it automatically, so as I'm adding new song I won't have to do anything.

I'd like to see how exactly may I deploy this behavior?

Comment: Do you have any code already? If you do, please post it here

Comment: I'm just at the design stage, no code yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, you should create a directory which contains all and only mp3 files and you'll read the songs from that directory.

On that note, you're going to have to read the metadata of the file to obtain the Artist and Song names. Example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21746415/15261366

As you can see here, you can extract song name, artist as well as the length of the song all from the metadata of the file (though the example aforementioned does not contain the example of how to read the length of a song).
[Metadata2go Pandemonium](https://www.metadata2go.com/result/51838df5-5cc3-4290-bf3b-bc11c79aa4df)

After reading all files, you can sort them on the Artist and Song name as desired (e.g. alphabetically).