# How can I extract Metadata from a .MP4 and a .AVI with native library in JAVA

Tags: java, mp4, avi

I try to make a media player and a video library for a school project, and I need to extract metadata from a .MP4 and .AVI to store in a XML files and can edit this metadata.

I did some research and I didn't find what I'm looking for, because I need a native Java library, and not a library that we need to install in our IDE.

And I have make my media player with JavaFX, and JavaFX can not read .avi media. So I need to convert this .avi to .mp4 is it possible to do this in Java with a native library?

Comment: *"I need a native java library, and not a library that we need to install in our IDE"* what do you mean? You mean something that is part of the standard library?

Comment: Yes exactly, sorry if it wasn't very clear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the metadata of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10824027/get-the-metadata-of-a-file)

Comment: I don't know I need to try, but I need to have the title, the autor,date and other basic information from a mp4

Comment: Yes it work, but that's not the metadata I want.

Comment: I still don't understand your request for "a native library". You will most certainly not find that in the Java standard library. But so what. Nobody writes real-world software which is just based on the Java standard library. What's the problem with using some external library?

Comment: it is a constraint to create my mediaplayer fix by my professor. Me too I don't understand why...

Comment: @Madarra Maybe your teacher wants you to use only the standard Java APIs instead of some third party APIs, is it what (s)he meant?

Comment: Yes its was that, I have asked him what a really want. Because i didn't really understand what's is the difference with standard Java APIs and third party APIs. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite clear what is meant by "native java library".
Java itself (JDK / JRE) does not support parsing of media meta data. The only possibility would be to use a third party library like "Apache Tika":

[How to read MP3 file tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645803/how-to-read-mp3-file-tags#answer-21746415)

Comment: Thanks for your response, I will use this my professor said it was allowed tu use this library.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the Java standard library.

```
public class YourClass {

    Path yourFile = ...;
    BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(yourFile, BasicFileAttributes.class);
    
    System.out.println("creationTime: " + attr.creationTime());
    System.out.println("lastAccessTime: " + attr.lastAccessTime());
    System.out.println("lastModifiedTime: " + attr.lastModifiedTime());
    
    System.out.println("isDirectory: " + attr.isDirectory());
    System.out.println("isOther: " + attr.isOther());
    System.out.println("isRegularFile: " + attr.isRegularFile());
    System.out.println("isSymbolicLink: " + attr.isSymbolicLink());
    System.out.println("size: " + attr.size());
}
```

This is platform dependent and may throw exceptions or return unexpected results.

Read more at [Managing Metadata (File and File Store Attributes)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html).

Comment: Thanks for your response men. That's part of what I was looking for with more information. I will use "Apache Tika" for more information about .mp4 files.

Comment: You're welcome. I hope it was of help