# How to add list of songs from res/raw in audio player in android

Tags: android, audio

I am creating audio player. I have stored audio files in raw folder. I have created list view for that. but I just don't know how to list those audio files in listview. I will be playing one by one songs in audio player.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Consider tagging this with `android` so that the people who might know the answer will see it.

Answer (score 1):

To create the list view it will be better to read the meta data of the file, You can get enough details to display in the list.
There are some java libraries to manipulate mp3 tags, my choice would be [javamusictag](http://javamusictag.sourceforge.net/docs.htm)

You can get more details from this existing SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527169/whats-the-easiest-way-to-extract-the-jpg-data-from-an-mp3-header-in-java)

To read the raw resource file try this

```
try {
    Resources res = getResources();
    InputStream inStream = res.openRawResource(R.raw.file);

    byte[] buff = new byte[inStream.available()];
    inStream.read(buff);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();            
}
```

but usually what the audio player program does is, read the file from the SD card. [Here](http://kunalmaemo.blogspot.com/2012/01/playing-audio-file-and-fetching.html) you can find some useful information regarding this kind of approach.